# MSVC warning 4611 regarding setjmp w/POD struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, compiler-warnings, setjmp

Trying to turn up some warning levels on a C codebase that also builds as C++.  I'm giving Visual Studio a shot (for some reason).

Got a warning about setjmp interactions, despite not seeing any relevant destructors.  so I did a test:

```
#include <setjmp.h>

struct X { int y; };

int main() {
    struct X x;

    jmp_buf buf;
    if (setjmp(buf) == 0) {
        longjmp(buf, 1);
    } else {
        // whatever.
    }
}
```

Enabling the warning on the command-line:

```
C:\wherever>cl /we4611 test.cpp
```

> test.cpp
>   test.cpp(9): error C4611: interaction between '_setjmp' and C++ object destruction is non-portable

This seems like an extremely useful warning--if it was warning me about crossing C++ destructor code.  But that's a POD type.  There shouldn't be any destructor code.

Am I missing something here, or did they botch this warning to the point of making it basically "you used setjmp in a C++ program"?

Comment: Does the warning mysteriously vanish if you enable optimization?  (This particular diagnostic may be sensitive to whether the compiler has _noticed_ that a type is POD, and it might not be so careful about noticing in the "minimize compilation time" default mode.)

Comment: @zwol With full optimization (`cl /we4611 /Ox test.cpp`) it still gives the warning.  :-(

Comment: I'm afraid that's me out of ideas, then.  I agree with your assessment that the warning is worthless if it triggers on PODs.

Comment: @zwol Oh well, thanks anyway.  I [added a suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/20354494) on the MS site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> did they botch this warning to the point of making it basically "you used setjmp in a C++ program"?

Looks to be the case.

I'd probably classify it as a bug, myself.  But it was easier to [make a suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/20354494) on the Microsoft website.  Suggestions can be voted on, there...